# Replicas never registered as available in deployment

Tags: kubernetes

For deploying out services, we have defined a kubernetes deployment, that we patch the container field of, each time we need to update.

This creates a new replicaset, and scales it correctly and the new pods become ready, however, when describing the  deployment, it only reports one replica available

```
kubectl describe deployment group-service 


CreationTimestamp:  Thu, 01 Dec 2016 16:36:08 +0100
Labels:         service=printix.service.groups
Selector:       service=printix.service.groups
Replicas:       2 updated | 2 total | 1 available | 1 unavailable
StrategyType:       RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds:    40
RollingUpdateStrategy:  1 max unavailable, 1 max surge
Conditions:
 Type       Status  Reason
 ----       ------  ------
 Available  True    MinimumReplicasAvailable
```

Am I misunderstanding this information? might this be a bug in kubernetes (it only started happening after an upgrade)? And does this have any consequences? I haven't been able to determine which of the replicas is actually registered as available.

```
kubectl verion: 
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.2", GitCommit:"08e099554f3c31f6e6f07b448ab3ed78d0520507", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-01-12T04:57:25Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.2+coreos.1", GitCommit:"3ed7d0f453a5517245d32a9c57c39b946e578821", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-01-18T01:43:45Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Answer (score 1):

> StrategyType:       RollingUpdate
>   MinReadySeconds:    40

You are performing a rolling update, which means this update will replace the original pod one by one, and finish in 40s as you defined. So at beginning of the update, this is normal. Did you meet this all the time?